# How to correctly locate a control in a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop

Consider the following code-behind for displaying a child window after clicking a button in the Main Window. The desired result is to have the child window placement show up just to the right of the menu button, in-line with the top of the menu button. (So the window shows right next to the control that activated it.)

```
    private void btnMenu2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu2 = new Menu2Window();

        //var winLocation = this.btnMenu2.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), Application.Current.MainWindow);
        //var winLocation = this.btnMenu2.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this.spLeftMenu);
        //var winLocation = this.spLeftMenu.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this.btnMenu2);
        var objLocation = this.spLeftMenu.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), this.spLeftMenu);
        var scnLocation = this.btnMenu2.PointToScreen(objLocation);

        //menu2.Left = scnLocation.X + btnMenu2.Width;
        menu2.Left = scnLocation.X + 50; // <- Why does this work but using btnMenu2.Width causes placement to be all over the place???

        menu2.Top = scnLocation.Y;
        menu2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The code as presented does work in the fashion needed, however I don't like using hard-coded values or magic numbers in code.

If you comment out the line with the hard-coded control width value (50) and un-comment the line using the button's width property, subsequent execution results in the menu window displaying in a sequence of locations that defy logic. It appears that it is getting a value from a random number generator rather than the control's width. I do see a pattern when its run several times, but getting 4 or 5 different locations because of a variation in property value responses each time the code is executed is quite frustrating.

What would be the RIGHT or correct approach here? How do I get a reliable value back from a WPF control property or am I asking too much?

XAML of Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="LocateTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LocateTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="DarkGray"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="750">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="spLeftMenu"
                    DataContext="MainWindow"
                    Orientation="Vertical" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="325" Width="50">
            <Button Content="B1" Height="50" Width="50"/>
            
            <Button x:Name="btnMenu2" 
                    Content="B2" 
                    Height="50" 
                    Click="btnMenu2_Click"/>
            
            <Button Content="B3" Height="50"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

XAML of Menu2 window:

````
<Window x:Class="LocateTest.Menu2Window"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LocateTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        Height="150" Width="280">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="Black"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" 
                Click="btnClose_Click"
                Width="25"
                Height="25"
                Content="X"
                Background="Black"
                Foreground="Red" Margin="245,10,10,115">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't explicitly set the width of `btnMenu2`, the value of its `Width` property will be `double.NaN`. Note that the `Width` value is not the actual width, but the requested width. Use the `ActualWidth` proeprty instead:

```
menu2.Left = scnLocation.X + btnMenu2.ActualWidth;
```

Comment: I was thinking of this same thing as I drove home today. The var type is important, but the new info to me was that there is an 'actualwidth' property; I spent way too much time in Winforms so it didn't immediately occur to me that I needed to find the 'as rendered' property values till I read your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about using Popup instead? You can put all you want on a Popup control instead of a window and set its StaysOpen property to true to make the user close it automatically through close button or whatever.